# How to read in multiple excel sheets into python when there is multiple possible names for a sheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have over 4000 xlsx files that each contain a sheet that is named ALMOST the same thing each time.

It always follows this format: XXX-XXX-001

However, the last number sometimes changes, and sometimes there is white space at the start or end of the sheet name. I've looked and there doesn't seem to be any regex option for pandas read_excel. Any suggestions? Is there some sort of 'if in ()' check I can do?

Thanks!

Comment: I would recommend you read the first row from every single excel file - with `sheet_name` equal to `None` this will return a dictionary where the sheetname are the keys and values are dataframes. then use a regex exp or string matching to find your sheet name in every dictionary of dataframes, you can then build this into your logic when reading it in workbooks. If you need help with above let me know.

Comment: Do you have only one sheet in files? Then take only first seet.

Answer (score 0):

If memory is not an issue, you can read all the sheet in the excel file first, and then filter the sheetname

first read the excel

```
df_dict = pd.read_excel(filename, sheetname=None)
```

Then filter the df name

```
dfname = list[df_dict]
wanted_df_name = ['XXX-XXX-001' in ele for ele in dfname][0]
```

finally take the df from the df_dict

```
wanted_df = df_dict[wanted_df_name]
```